# Difference between JWK generated with different libraries

Tags: java, php, jwt, jwk, jose

I am working on migration from php to Java, while doing so , I encountered a JWK that is being generated with spomky-jose/JWKFactory (let's call that JWK-P) while for generating JWK in Java , I am using nimbus-jose-jwt library (let's call that JWK-J). Both of these JWKs are identical except that x5c parameter of JWK-P has some new line characters ("\n") , does this make a difference ? If yes, how should I deal with same?

**excerpt from JWK-P :**
MIID4DCCAsigAwIBAgIJAOYsgV+iL1VXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGEMQswCQYD **\n**VQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UECAwCVVAxDjAMBgNVBAcMBU5vaWRhMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZu **\n**YXV

**excerpt from JWK-J :**
MIID4DCCAsigAwIBAgIJAOYsgV+iL1VXMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGEMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UECAwCVVAxDjAMBgNVBAcMBU5vaWRhMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZuYXV

PS : both JWKs are generated using same PEM certificate.

Comment: Try it and see, whats the worst that can happen

Comment: spomky-labs/jose is deprecated since 2018. would you mind to use a maintained library?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it makes a difference but there ought to be no whitespace, such as new line characters, in the x5c members' representation. JWK-P is incorrect in its implementation.